# buy/sell alert script for determined market structure sequence

Tags: pine-script-v5

i already have plotted the market structure (higher high, lower low, etc.) but i have a problem to create alert script when determined market structure formed, for example i need sell alert when the market structure formed : LL,LH,HL
help me please, how the script supposed to be?

[image: marketstructure]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)